# Using the python chr() function with combining diacritics

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I am writing a Python script to add diacritical marks (in the U+03XX range) to strings. However, `chr()` is complaining every time I try to convert a number in that range to a character. (This is Python 3, so no `unichr`.)

Here is a truncated version of my code:

```
    strl = list(input())
    args = input().split(" ")
    strl[int(args[0])]+=chr(int(args[1])+0x300) #this is the line that breaks
```

It crashes with the following exception:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0300' in position 16: character maps to <undefined>
```

So how can I turn an integer into the string representation of a combining diacritic?

(For example, if I put the string `"accent marks"` in for `strl`, and `"0 0"` for `args`, I want `strl` to end up as `["à","c","c","e","n","t"," ","m","a","r","k","s"]`

UPDATE: in the comments, delnan explained to me that `chr()` is working fine, but that the program is refusing to print the string. How can I print strings (already stored in variables) containing characters from this code block?

Comment: Please give some sample values for `strl` and `args`.

Comment: Which version of Python specifically? It works on 3.3.2.

Comment: I was able to get  `chr(0x300)` to run on `Python 3.3`, so I suspect your problem is with `int(args[1])` but cannot test that without the value that is actually causing a break.

Comment: @merlin2011 The crash specifically says "can't encode character '\u0300'", and I know that args[1] is a valid int value, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: The exception type and message indicates it properly created the U+0300 code point, and only failed to encode it into some encoding (e.g. when writing to a byte stream). Which line does the traceback point at?

Comment: @delnan Thanks. So the problem is printing the string, not translating it. Thanks, and I'll update the question to match.

Comment: Your console doesn't support printing characters in that range. If it's a Unix console you are probably missing some locale settings. If it's a Windows console that's just the way it is, the MS C stdlib doesn't Unicode.

Comment: @bobince Yeah, that's probably it; I'm running it on Windows 7, using Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not with `chr()`; the problem is simply that the Windows console cannot display the characters in question. Thank you to all who helped me figure this out in the comments.